# Centering images with text-align

Tags: html, css, css-position, centering, text-align

I am creating a simple site and I found out that I can center `<img>` tags with `text-align: center;` but id does not work on block elements like `<div>` for example. Can someone explain to me how exactly the `text-align` works and if it's god practice to use it to align images?

Thank you very much in advance :)

**UPDATE**

I also know about the `margin: 0 auto;` which in some situations works and in other situations it refuses to center elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It totally depends on your requirement, there are various ways to do so, one is that `img` is an `inline` element, so setting it to `block` and using `margin: auto;` will `center` your `img`

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rgjuc/)

Another way is which you are trying to attempt, which needs `text-align: center;` to be declared on the parent element and not the `img` tag itself, cuz I doubt you are using `text-align: center;` for the `img` tag and not for the parent... Where in the above solution we are targeting the `img` tag, so there's a difference between the two..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rgjuc/1/)

What's the good point here?

- You don't have to make the `img` a `block` level element.
- No need of `margin: auto;`

What's the bad point here?

- If you have `p` elements inside the `div`, they will be centered aligned as well, because the `align` property is inherited.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rgjuc/2/)

So what to do now? Align the `p` elements to the `left` using `text-align: left;` property, and here we will be targetting `p` like

This will keep the image centered and will align the `p` to the `left`

```
.wrap {
    text-align: center;
}

.wrap p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rgjuc/3/)

---

Last but not the least, we can also use *CSS Positioning* where you can have a parent element set to `position: relative;` and than we use `position: absolute;` for the `img` tag, and than we assign `top: 50%` and `left: 50%` and than we deduct the 1/2 of total `height` and `width` of your `img` by using `margin-top` and `margin-left` properties respectively. This method comes handy in case where you need the image vertically as well as horizontally centered. (This method will require fixed `height` and `width` to be declared)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
 <img src="img.png">
</div>

img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: can you please also explain the functionality behind `margin: auto;`? Thank you

Comment: `margin: auto;` is the same as `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` together. It just covers both

Comment: The auto margins will force the image to be centered, by creating a same-size margin on the left and right side. As Adsy said, this can be done in a single line using just margin: auto. I wanted to show right/left for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to use text-align property for the texts only (of course there could be exceptions). And for centering images you can simply do like this:

```
img{
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

A 'div', or any block element, without a declared width, can't be centered with `margin: 0 auto;`, but images will. 'Auto' counts pixels for you and make an element appear in the center

Answer (score 1):

See W3: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#alignment-prop

Whether you want to use margin:0 auto; or text-align:center , this really depends on what you're doing exactly and the surrounding markup, context.

I always try to use text-align:center; when possible. I also define images as a block which helps auto margins.

Also a great article by Chris at CSS tricks: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 1):

The property `text-algin:center` basically does what it says. Its *supposed* to center **text**. You can either apply directly to the text that you want to center or apply it to the parent div. In this case **every text** within this div will be centered.

The better practise to center, e.g., images, is to use `margin: 0 auto;` as many have already suggested. Specifying **auto** tells the browser to automatically determine the left and right margins itself and to set them equal. It therefore guarantees that both margins have the same size, which is why the object is centered horizontally.

Hope that helps!